# Determining the scalar values

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the scalars $c$ and $d$ so that the set of vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ for
which $x_1 +x_2 +x_3 = 0$, $x_1 −x_2 +cx_3 = 0$, and $x_1 −x_2 −x_3 = d$ form a subspace of dimension
$2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_4$ is unaffected by these equations, it is clearly a free variable, and will contribute to exactly one dimension of the resulting subspace. It is therefore equivalent to find the constants $c$ and $d$ such that the set of vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying the given equations, has dimension 1.

Writing the equations as an augmented matrix, we get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & c & 0 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & d
\end{pmatrix}$$

after some row reducing you get a matrix which is row equivalent to

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & d \\
0 & 2 & 2 & -d \\
0 & 0 & c+1 & -d \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The subspace being dimension 1 corresponds to there being $3-1=2$ pivots in the echelon form. This means that $c+1=0$ (as the first two colums clearly contain pivots), which forces $d=0$ as well.

So the answer is $c=-1,d=0$.